# How to generate localisation for urls having slug?

Tags: django, internationalization

I have a Django 1.7 project and I have been able to generate localised urls using the following format -

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

url(_(r'^about-us/$'), 'aboutus', name='aboutus'),
```

My problem is that I have following urls -

```
url(_(r'^products/$'), 'products_list', name='products'),
url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'products_list', name='products_category'),
```

I am generating language based slug using modeltranslation package. But, I am unable to generate local url using this format -

```
url(_(r'^products') + '/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'products_list', name='products_category'),
```

So, what is happening is that say for German I have 'produkte; and a product name soap slug is 'seife'. So, instead of /produkte/seife, I am getting /products/seife. How can I generate /produkte/seife?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the whole URL regex (including the slug part) to `ugettext_lazy` ([Translating URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns):

```
url(_(r'^products/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$'), 'products_list', name='products_category'),
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. And, in translation just do 'produkte/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$'. Works!

Comment: The problem is now the slug is not recognized when request is for german language.

Comment: Your translation has` \\w`. Ist this a typo?

Comment: @RaviRanaji did my answer help you? If so accept it, please.